# Complex random point generation

Tags: c, function, random, complex-numbers, fractals

Using C, how can I generate a random point on the complex plain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a decent starting point, you could use [`rand()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand). To generate a random number between -2 and +2, you can do:

```
float f = 4 * ((rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) - 0.5f);
```

If you repeat this process, you can get an `x` and a `y`:

```
float x = 4 * ((rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) - 0.5f);
float y = 4 * ((rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) - 0.5f);
```

Now just use `x` and `y` as your complex number.

Also, be sure to call [`srand()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/srand) once (and only once) at the start of your program to seed the random number generator.